# Pattern for passing data from data collectors to master thread

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I have this structure of network application:

`Master->[Own Thread] Control class->[Own Thread] Data Receiver Class->Data Processor Class -> Database class`

Now I need to process data from sources in one central point to be able to get context of all data streams and preprocess them before saving to database.

What is the best way of doing this?

Thx

Comment: [Message queues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue)?

Comment: Thanks, this is it. So obvious, I was confused by _Message_ in its name...